# SQL Server Always On does not send requests to read only replica

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have created an Availability Group with one primary and one secondary read only replica. The configuration is as below: 
[image: Always On Configuration]

Now I connect to the listener using SSMS with parameter `APPLICATIONINTENT=READONLY;` but all read and write requests are sent to primary server as is shown in Profiler:

[image: Profiler shows requests are sent to the primary server]

Is there any configuration mistake of me?